# IMacros cannot find a POS (position) in Outlook Web App-See video

Tags: email, macros, imacros

I'm trying to create emails from a .csv file but the TO; field and the BODY field cannot be identified by IMACROS. I attached a video to show you what I'm seeing and to better explain my question. http://screencast.com/t/euhT6X17

Below is the error and script:

```
RuntimeError: element INPUT specified by SRC:https://webmail-be.tomtomgroup.com/owa/14.3.169.1/themes/resources/clear1x1.gif was not found, line 15 (Error code: -921)
```

Script:

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
SET !DATASOURCE capterra.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=https://webmail-be.tomtomgroup.com/owa/?modurl=0
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:New
TAB T=2
wait seconds=4
CLICK X=114 Y=46
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:divTo CONTENT={{!COL5}}
wait seconds=4
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:txtSubj CONTENT={{!COL5}}
wait seconds=4
CLICK X=28 Y=32
TAG POS=30 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=SRC:https://webmail-be.tomtomgroup.com/owa/14.3.169.1/themes    /resources/clear1x1.gif CONTENT={{!COL5}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Send
SET !LOOP 2
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this.

```
TAG POS=30 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=SRC:https://webmail-be.tomtomgroup.com/owa/14.3.169.1/themes/resources/clear1x1.gif CONTENT={{!COL5}}
```